# how to create update function for bash script

Tags: git, bash

I want to create a update function for my bash script so that in the future any changes I commit to the script which is stored on github can be updated by the end-users. I can't find any example of an update function for bash.

if I just make a function like so:

```
function update(){
  git clone https://path/to/my/repo.git
}
```

It simply creates another copy of my repo in the present directory that I'm in. Adding a path directly to the script doesn
t work either. How can I make it happen?

Comment: `function` and `()` are redundant.  Just write `update() { ... }`.  (Omit the word 'function'.)

Comment: that other guy. im in my home folder. git update does not work because 'update' is not a git command. @William Pursell. i cant remove the word function because its a function in my script. i removed the word function and the update function did not work.

Comment: What you're looking for is probably `git pull`. Or perhaps `git push`. Not really clear what you're asking actually.

Comment: git pull is probably what im looking for but it aborts telling me to commit my changes before i merge which i want to do in the first place.  @Matthieu Moy, basically lets say you have a script and in the menu of the script there is a choice to update the script to the latest version of it from github. you click update and it updates your script to the latest version. What i want is to write that same function so that if i make changes to my repo, users would be able to update to the latest version of the script.

Comment: @Red5tar The developer should edit, commit and push. The user should pull (but not edit). Don't try to test it where the user and the developer is the same account

Comment: To define a function, you need to give the name followed by `()`.  The keyword `function` is not necessary.  How are you invoking the function?  There is no reason you should ever see git give an error claiming that 'update' is not a git command unless you are doing something very strange.   (eg, invoking `git update` to try and invoke the shell function that you have defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed an update function in a subscript without git pulling the whole directrory, it ended up like this:
(from https://bitbucket.org/jupiter126/sheldon/raw/master/backup_skel.sh)

`if [ "$(grep 'autoupdate=1' $directory/backup_$(hostname).sh)" != "" ]; then
    oldver=$(cat "$directory/backup_skel.sh"|grep -v "("|grep backupversion|cut -f2 -d"=")
    newver=$(curl -s https://bitbucket.org/jupiter126/sheldon/raw/master/backup_skel.sh|grep -v "("|grep backupversion|cut -f2 -d"=")
    if [ "$newver" -gt "$oldver" ]; then
        echo "new version detected, updating backup script"
        mv "$directory/backup_skel.sh" "$directory/backup_skel.old"
        $wwwget -q https://bitbucket.org/jupiter126/sheldon/raw/master/backup_skel.sh -O"$directory/backup_skel.sh" && sleep 2 && chmod +x "$directory/backup_skel.sh" && sleep 2 && exec "$directory/backup_skel.sh"
    fi
fi`

Answer (score 0):

If the update function is ment for the end user to update there copy of the script, this might be what your looking for.

```
    update(){
    cd /tmp 
    git clone https://path/to/my/repo.git
    # cd into the cloned directory if need to reach script 
    mv script.sh /to/location/of/old/script
    # or 
    rm /location/of/old/script.sh
    mv script.sh /to/location/of/old/script
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but as mentioned, don't be dev and user in the same directory!

```
function update {
    git pull
}
```

Eventually if you need to perform a specific command in case an update was available, you can use something like

```
function update {
    if [[ "$(git pull|grep Already)" = "" ]]; then
        echo "script has just been updated"
    else
        echo "no update was available"
    fi
}
```

Also, one thing that can come in handy if you do this is to have a separate settings file, that you source from your script and "[.gitignore](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/)" - so people don't have to reset their settings at each update

Comment: Better to write such conditions as `if ! git pull | grep -q Already; then`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `git -f pull origin a_branch:tmp_branch` to force pulling new changes from a_branch to a tmp_branch every some second.

```
function update {
  cd the/repo/path
  git pull -f origin a_branch:tmp_branch
}
```